# Dynamic index structure load translating to Array when calling a json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, type-conversion

I have a file structure like this:

```
{
  "hierarchy": [
    {
      "type": "folder",
      "name": "src",
      "child": [
        {
          "type": "folder",
          "name": "assets",
          "child": [
            {
              "type": "folder",
              "name": "styles",
              "child": [
                {
                  "type": "file",
                  "name": "style.css",
                  "data": "style"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "folder",
              "name": "scripts",
              "child": [
                {
                  "type": "file",
                  "name": "script.js",
                  "data": "script"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "file",
          "name": "index.html",
          "data": "html"
        },
        {
          "type": "file",
          "name": "manifest.json",
          "data": "manifest"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "folder",
      "name": "dist",
      "child": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Listen to this root directory and all sub directories and create a Array which mirrors this directory structure, each node contains type, name, path, and children:

```
[
    ["folder","src","./"],
    ["file","index.html","./src/"],         
    ["file","index.html","./src/"],
    ["folder","assets","./src/"],
    ["folder","styles","./src/assets/"],
    ["folder","scripts","./src/assets/"],
    ["file","style.css","./src/assets/styles/"],
    ["file","script.js","./src/assets/scripts/"],
    ["folder","dist","./"]
]
```

I want to dynamically listen to the JSON file and create an array as shown in the example.

Comment: @rule I didn't try anything appropriate. it didn't work.

Comment: Why does the last folder have `"child": [null]`? Shouldn't it be `"child": [ ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this recursively like so:

```
function getEntriesFromHierarchy(hierarchy, path, entries = []) {
    entries.push([ hierarchy.type, hierarchy.name, path ]);

    if(hierarchy.type === "folder") {
        hierarchy.child.forEach(childHierarchy =>
            getEntriesFromHierarchy(childHierarchy, path + hierarchy.name + "/", entries)
        );
    }

    return entries;
}

let results = yourObject.hierarchy.reduce((acc, hierarchy) => 
    acc.concat(getEntriesFromHierarchy(hierarchy, "./"))
, []);
```

`getEntriesFromHierarchy` adds the entry corresponding to the hierarchy object to the array `entries`, and if the hierarchy is a folder, it calls itself on each child hierarchy of that folder. It passes the array `entries` so that it can be used instead of creating a new array each time, thus all the files in a hierarchy are contained in the same array.

Since your object `hierarchy` property is an array of hierarchies, we use `reduce` to concatenate all the resulting arrays into the `results` array. Each call of `getEntriesFromHierarchy` on hierarchies in the array `hierarchy` will return an array of results corresponding to that particular hierarchy, so we need to merge all those arrays into one, and that's what the second part of the code is responsible for.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand completely .

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach and iterate the given tree.

```js
function getFlat(array, path = './') {
    return array.reduce((r, { type, name, child = [] }) => {
        r.push([type, name, path], ...getFlat(child, `${path}${name}/`));
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var tree = { hierarchy: [{ type: "folder", name: "src", child: [{ type: "folder", name: "assets", child: [{ type: "folder", name: "styles", child: [{ type: "file", name: "style.css", data: "style" }] }, { type: "folder", name: "scripts", child: [{ type: "file", name: "script.js", data: "script" }] }] }, { type: "file", name: "index.html", data: "html" }, { type: "file", name: "manifest.json", data: "manifest" }] }, { type: "folder", name: "dist", child: [] }] },
    result = getFlat(tree.hierarchy);    

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```